# AVA in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, translation

Trying to figure out the proper way to write Ava in Japanese. I see there are several types of Japanese alphabets so lost on which is the correct way. It's my daughter's name and she's a martial artist so wanted to get her name done in Japanese.

Thanks

Comment: http://ellegirl.jp/tag/ava-phillippe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how her name is pronounced in English. If it's pronounced "AH-va," I would write it as in the link l'electeur offered: アヴァ. If it's pronounced "EH-va," I would write it: エヴァ。

In general, translation requests are out of the scope of this forum, but yesterday I was wondering how to write "Laertes" in Katakana, and it turns out there are a bunch of different ways, which I thought was interesting.

Addendum: While エヴァ is a common transliteration, I agree with Ben below that エイヴァ is more faithful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's pronounced EH VA so I had come across エヴァ and I also came across アヴァ which is where I was confused. Thanks for the clarification and response. Appreciate it.

Comment: エヴァ would only really make sense if it's pronounced with the same vowels as "never", which seems odd as a pronunciation of that spelling to me. If the first syllable actually rhymes with "may", which seems more likely, I would have thought エイヴァ is the natural choice.

Comment: Agreed. I’ll edit.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was looking more into it and depending how you pronounce determines the "spelling" so I did come エイヴァ as the one to use for ay-vah.